# Error assingning the output of a command to a variable in bash (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wonder why this command:

```
FILE=`file /usr/bin/java | tr -d \`\' | awk '{print $5}'`
```

Results in this error message:

```
bash: command substitution: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
bash: command substitution: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

If I run the previous command without assigning it to a variable, it works as expected:

```
$ file /usr/bin/java | tr -d \`\' | awk '{print $5}'
/etc/alternatives/java
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how can I successfully assign the output value to a variable?

**Note:** for the curious, I'm trying to find the pointed path to a binary file from a symbolic link, so I can find out if it is a 32 or 64 bits file (in a generic way, not using something like `java -version`)

**Note 2:** I've tried removing quotes with `sed` instead of `tr`, but it returns the same error

Thank you very much in advance, regards...

Nacho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's because you enclosed the commands inside back-ticks. Use `$()` instead of backticks.

```
FILE=$(file /usr/bin/java | tr -d \`\' | awk '{print $5}')
```

Comment: Not the back-ticks are the problem of the original code but the lack of escaping inside them. The command line included in back ticks contains two backslashes and they need to be escaped but they are not.

Comment: Thank you very much Avinash Raj! This solved my problem

Comment: @axiac you're right, escaping it like this works fine too `FILE=\`file /usr/bin/java | tr -d \\\`\' | awk '{print $5}'\``